# Switch Statement Not Handling NS_ENUM values

Tags: objective-c, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum defined in a objective-c header that looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface CustomerAndProspectMapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TypeEnum)
{
    PROSPECT,
    CUSTOMER

};
@end
```

Then in the implementation I have a function that takes a TypeEnum as a parameter and uses a switch to run some conditional code:

```
-(void) handleTestNavigation:(NSString *)accountId :(TypeEnum)accountType
{
    switch(accountType)
    {
        CUSTOMER:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"customerDetails" sender:accountId];
            break;
        }

        PROSPECT:
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"prospectDetails" sender:accountId];
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, both options for the enum have a corresponding path in the switch. Yet for some reason, I get a compiler warning saying

> Enumeration values 'PROSPECT' and 'CUSTOMER' not handled in
>   switch

Just to make sure, I put some breakpoints in that method. As the warning indicated, it fell though without ever hitting a case. I also tried renaming the enum values just to make sure they were not conflicting somewhere and still nothing. I'm completely stumped here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the keyword `case`.

```
switch(accountType)
{
    case CUSTOMER:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"customerDetails" sender:accountId];
        break;
    }

    case PROSPECT:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"prospectDetails" sender:accountId];
        break;
    }

}
```

---

NOTE: The code you posted created two [labels](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto).

Comment: It's funny what you can miss. I've been programming C-based languages for nearly 30 years and I stared at the question for a few minutes trying to figure out the problem. I felt stupid after scrolling down to your answer and realizing it was something so simple. :)

Comment: *facepalm* I knew it had to be something silly, but I didn't expect anything THAT silly. Just goes to show the value of a second pair of eyes sometimes. Thanks so much.